# An array in Python seems assigned by reference but has a different id than the original array

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

In the following code I create an `numpy.ndarray` and assign it to `x1`. Then I assign `x1` to `x2` by reference.

So far no surprises: when I modify an element of `x1` the modification is reflected in `x2` and `id(x1) == id(x2)`.

However, when I assign `x3 = x2[:]` I get a new object `x3` with a different id but then, when I modify an element in `x1`, the same element is modified also in `x3`.

Please can someone explain this?

```
import numpy as np
# clear x1, x2, x3 from the workspace`
if 'x1' in locals(): del x1
if 'x2' in locals(): del x2
if 'x3' in locals(): del x3

# create x1, x2 will be a reference to the same array
# how about x3 ?
x1 = np.random.randint(10, size=(1,5))
print('x1 =', x1)
x2 = x1
print('x2 =', x2)
x3 = x2[:]
print('x3 =', x3)
print(f"id(x1) = {id(x1)}\nid(x2) = {id(x2)}\nid(x3) = {id(x3)}")

x1[0,0] = 1e2
print('x1 =', x1)
print('x2 =', x2)
print('x3 =', x3)
```

OUTPUT:

```
x1 = \[\[8 7 2 5 7\]\]
x2 = \[\[8 7 2 5 7\]\]
x3 = \[\[8 7 2 5 7\]\]
id(x1) = 137230814029232
id(x2) = 137230814029232
id(x3) = 137230814025104
x1 = \[\[100 7 2 5 7\]\]
x2 = \[\[100 7 2 5 7\]\]
x3 = \[\[100 7 2 5 7\]\]
```

If I assign as `x3 = x2.copy()` or first create the object as `x3 = np.zeros_like(x2)` and then copy `x3[:] = x2[:]` I get the result I expected, i.e. an element modified in `x1` does not change anything in `x3`

Comment: Short answer: `numpy` has different rules than anything in Python aside from Python's `memoryview` type (which has similar rules, but is fairly obscure). Slices make new *views* of the same underlying data, the neither alias (like plain assignment) nor copy (like explicit copies). The duplicates cover all this in detail.